# Single line EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to make the edittext single line. The edittext does comes up as single line but on pressing enter it the cursor comes to the second line and I need to stop this. The singleLine attribute is deprecated so I do not want to use that.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Can someone let me know what am I goind wrong over here ?

Comment: I don't see any where, singleLine is deprecated..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine check for reference

Comment: @Pragnani When using the Eclipse IDE, Single Line is under the Deprecated caption...

Answer (score 45):

Set `android:inputType` to something different than "none", use "text", "number" or whatever should be entered in the `EditText`. This way you can make the `EditText` single-lined. (Of course you shouldn't use "textMultiLine" then ;))

Comment: Correct answer. It should be `android:maxLines="1"` to make it look like single line EditText and `android:inputType="text"` to prevent entering a new line. Therefore one should combine these to get the desired outcome. and `android:lines="1"` is not necessory

Comment: saved the day :) because android:maxLines="1" alone without changing inputType isn't enough,
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

Use this

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

instead of,

```
android:lines="1"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: singleLine is deprecated and hence do not want to use it.

Comment: android:singleLine="true" is crash my app.

Comment: @onder Not really. You may missed some other

Comment: @mobiledev Can you please give the reference where it says the [android:singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) is deprecated? I cannot see it there for API 23.

Comment: `singleLine` did the job on API 16 while `maxline` didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Change,

android:inputType="none"

to

android:inputType="text" or android:inputType="number"

according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

use this code :

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/Et_loginEmail"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
  android:hint="Email Address"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:ellipsize="end"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This alone is enough to make single line in EditText.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fullname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Full Name"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

`android:inputType="text"` alone solves the single line in `EditText`.

You need to choose your desired `inputType` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

change the `android:inputType="none"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

to

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```